# Exception while passing float value from array to coordinates

Tags: iphone, ios

i am getting exception over these lines of code dont know why its giving so ..Help me out .. 
reason is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:   
'-[__NSArrayI floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c57840'

coord.latitude = [[[self.holdingArray objectAtIndex:k] 
valueForKey:@"latitude"]floatValue];
 coord.longitude = [[[self.holdingArray objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"longitude"]  
 floatValue];
```

**Edit 1**

```
 -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[appDelegate.dealerDataGlobalArray removeAllObjects];
NSString *requestString;

requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.hvinfotech.net/projects/carwash
/search.php?search=%@",textField.text];
NSString *strCOntents1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:requestString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"Data: %@",strCOntents1);

NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  
URLWithString:requestString]];
DealerDetailParser *parser = [[DealerDetailParser alloc] 
initDealerDetailParserXMLParser];
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
[xmlParser parse];
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSLog(@"dealerDataGlobalArray...... %@",[appDelegate.dealerDataGlobalArray 
description]);
[holdingArray addObject:appDelegate.dealerDataGlobalArray];
NSLog(@"holdingArray...... %@",holdingArray);
flagForHoldingArray = YES;    
[self loadOurAnnotations]; 
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

i have edited so that it can be more clear. I am calling the webservice to get the data corresponding to what is entered in text field. After that i call the method in which previous line o code were posted...

**Edit2**

it gives like

```
    2012-01-23 00:27:35.475 CarWashApp[2584:11603] (
    {
    businessdesc = "having a garage and teamof 10members, originaly belongs to mumbai 
    maharashtra.";
    "businessdesc_de" = "having a garage and teamof 10members, originaly belongs to 
    mumbai maharashtra.";
    city = vadodra;
    "city_de" = "dadar_de";
    companyname = "Maruti Suzki Ltd";
    "companyname_de" = "Maruti Suzki Ltd _de";
    contactname = "bijju sharma";
    "contactname_de" = "bijju sharma_de";
    coupondetails = "10% Discount";
    "coupondetails_de" = "10% Discount _de";
    email = "bsharma@gmail.com";
    friday = "Friday: Closed";
    happyhour = "10:00 AM to 5:00 PM";
    id = 5;
    latitude = "22.30731";
    logo = "http://www.hvinfotech.net/projects/carwash/upload/images/Sunset.jpg";
    longitude = "73.181098";
    monday = "Monday: Closed";
    payment = Visa;
    payments = "";
    phone1 = 07932453453;
    phone2 = 07934344444;
    postcode = JU113;
    saturday = "Saturday:9:30 AM - 4:00 PM";
    services = "";
    state = Groningen;
    "state_de" = Groningen;
    streetaddress1 = "500 golf Road,";
    "streetaddress1_de" = "sectore 5 d_de";
    streetaddress2 = "airport Road";
    "streetaddress2_de" = "";
    sunday = "Sunday:9:30 AM - 4:00 PM";
    thursday = "Thursday: Closed";
    tuesday = "Tuesday:9:30 AM - 4:00 PM";
    website = "http://hvinfotechPvtLtd.com";
    wednesday = "Wednesday: Closed";
}
 )
  2012-01-23 00:27:43.434 CarWashApp[2584:11603] (
"22.30731"
)
```

i need only above value i.e "22.30731" as coordinate but its showing error if i also write like
    coord.latitude = [[self.holdingArray objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"latitude"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rayfleck said, the object in the array might be not be the kind of object you're expecting it to be. Use the debugger or `NSLog()` to find out what object it actually is.

Another possibility, is you might have a memory management bug somewhere. Do you have ARC enabled?

And finally, it could be a thread safety issue. In that case, best of luck finding it! There isn't really any easy way to track down threading issues, except read every line of code and try to find the mistake.

***EDIT:***

You have this line of code:

```
[holdingArray addObject:appDelegate.dealerDataGlobalArray];
```

It looks like you are adding an array object to the `holdingArray` array. Array objects will return another array when you send `valueForKey:` to them (lookup valueForKey in the documentation for NSArray...).

Anyway, the array object doesn't respond to `floatValue`. Only `NSString` and `NSNumber` objects respond to `floatValue`.

You should `NSLog()` these objects, because I think they are not what you expect them to be:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.holdingArray objectAtIndex:k]);
NSLog(@"%@", [[self.holdingArray objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"latitude"]);
```

Comment: plz see the above edits. loadingourannotations- method where i am passing key values of lat and long to coordinates.

Comment: Now that you've sent more details, I don't think it's a memory management error. But in general, I recommend turning ARC *on* to avoid bugs.

Comment: you need to find out what objects are in `holdingArray` and work out what messages you can send to it.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of objects are in self.holdingArray - dictionaries?
Ok, what kind of object is in the dictionary for key "longitude"?  It appears that they are arrays.
It is often good practice to break apart these kinds of nested statements, so that you can easily debug.

Comment: plz see above editsm not used any dictionary.Should i use dictionary to old the data coming from webservice ??? then to array??